# Is it possible to re-save a model created with Tf-nightly as a model for tensorflow 2.2.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a model created with `model.save()` using `tf-nightly` and wish to re-save/convert that model to a tensorflow 2.2.0 model, is that possible? If so, do you have any tips on how?

I tried this:

```
from keras import models    

model = models.load_model('53', compile=False) #tensorflow 2.2.0 model
model = model.load_weights('20210120') #tf-nighly weights

model.save('210120_Test')
```

And the output is:

```
>       4 model = model.load_weights('20210120')
>       5 
> ----> 6 model.save('210120_Test')
>       7 # model = model.load('aug1')
>       8 
> 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

And when i try to load the tf-nightly model from start:

```
    TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups')
```

When i try to convert model to tflite this error occur.

```
CNNmodel= model
      2 converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(CNNmodel)
----> 3 tflite_model = converter.convert()
      4 
      5 # Save the model.

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py in convert(self)
    516         input_tensors=input_tensors,
    517         output_tensors=output_tensors,
--> 518         **converter_kwargs)
    519 
    520     if self._is_calibration_quantize():

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py in toco_convert_impl(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, enable_mlir_converter, *args, **kwargs)
    494       input_data.SerializeToString(),
    495       debug_info_str=debug_info_str,
--> 496       enable_mlir_converter=enable_mlir_converter)
    497   return data
    498 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str, debug_info_str, enable_mlir_converter)
    225       stdout = _try_convert_to_unicode(stdout)
    226       stderr = _try_convert_to_unicode(stderr)
--> 227       raise ConverterError("See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
    228   finally:
    229     # Must manually cleanup files.

ConverterError: See console for info.
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': Ops that can be supported by the flex runtime (enabled via setting the -emit-select-tf-ops flag): ResizeNearestNeighbor,ResizeNearestNeighbor,ResizeNearestNeighbor,ResizeNearestNeighbor,ResizeNearestNeighbor,ResizeNearestNeighbor.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Load model in `tf-nightly`
2. Save weights
3. load weights in tf 2.2.0
4. save model in tf.2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
model = model.load_weights('20210120')
```

model.load_weights doesnt return anything so when you assign it model, model becomes None.

change it to

```
from keras import models    

model = models.load_model('53', compile=False) #tensorflow 2.2.0 model
model.load_weights('20210120') #tf-nighly weights

model.save('210120_Test')
```

link for tutorial
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load